Descarga de archivos .jpg | .pdf de servidor FTP en C# Windows Forms
estoy haciendo una aplicación de escritorio en donde enlisto los archivos de mi servidor ftp en un DataGridView y después los descargo a la carpeta de descargas. Él detalle esta en que los archivos descargados no se pueden visualizar por el hecho de que los codifica en UTF8, ya lo intente con UTF16  y 32 sigue el detalle
Este es mi código:
public void DescargaArchivos(string Archivo)
    {
        FtpWebRequest dirFtp = ((FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://Server/" + Archivo));

        NetworkCredential cr = new NetworkCredential("User", "Pass");
        dirFtp.Credentials = cr;

        dirFtp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dirFtp.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());

        string res = reader.ReadToEnd();

        // Obtenemos el nombre del usuario actual
        string userFolder = Environment.UserName;
        // Almacenamos la ruta de la carpeta de descargas en una string
        string pathToSaveFile = "C:\\Users\\" + userFolder + "\\Downloads\\";
        // Guardarlo en la carpeta de descargas
        string ficLocal = Path.Combine(pathToSaveFile, Path.GetFileName(Archivo));
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ficLocal, false, Encoding.UTF8);
        sw.Write(res);
        sw.Close();

        // Cerrar el stream abierto.
        reader.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("Descarga Finalizada, Ruta del archivo: " + pathToSaveFile, "Mensaje", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }

Alguien sabe de algún método para realizarlo
De antemano Gracias!!!

Y si lo haces sin encoding??? ->  StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ficLocal, false);

@Yussef ya lo intente y siguen si poderse visualizar

@Yussef ahora con el cambio ya es posible visualizar los archivos, muchas gracias

Lo que pasa es que conviertes lo binario en una representación a string, cuando una imagen es netamente binaria. En esta parte:
string res = reader.ReadToEnd();
//más código
sw.Write(res);

Prueba guardar en binario, algo como:
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dirFtp.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
using MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(); //usamos MemoryStream, porque él permite retornar un array de bytes
reader.BaseStream.CopyTo(ms); //traspasamos a MemoryStream

string userFolder = Environment.UserName;

string pathToSaveFile = "C:\\Users\\" + userFolder + "\\Downloads\\";

string ficLocal = Path.Combine(pathToSaveFile, Path.GetFileName(Archivo));
File.WriteAllBytes(ficLocal, ms.ToArray()); //creamos el archivo a partir del array de bytes

